# How to retrieve entry value in tkinter from a custom form

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Wrote a custom frame class so I can easily generate labels, entries etc.
I can input the number of labels, entries I want each form to have. By creating different instances of the class I don't need to write lots of labels and entries each time.
But when I run the code nothing happens. I get no error to guide me.
If I place a print statement in get_first_entry(self) function then it prints the value from the entry, but I would like to access the value from outside the class.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, num_labels, num_entries, num_buttons, label_names=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        # If label names are provided, use them instead of default labels
        if label_names is None:
            label_names = [f"Label {i+1}" for i in range(num_labels)]
        
        # Create labels and entries
        self.entries = []
        
        
        for i in range(num_labels):
            label = tk.Label(self, text=label_names[i])
            label.grid(row=i, column=0)
        
        
        for i in range(num_entries):
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
            self.entries.append(entry)
        
        # Create buttons

        for i in range(num_buttons):
            if i == 0:
                button = tk.Button(self, text=f"Get RA", command=self.get_first_entry)
            elif i == 1:
                button = tk.Button(self, text=f"Get DEC", command=self.get_second_entry)
            #else:
                #button = tk.Button(self, text=f"Button {i+1}")
            button.grid(row=num_labels+i, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2)
    
    def get_first_entry(self):
        value = self.entries[0].get()
        return value
       
        
    def get_second_entry(self):
        value = self.entries[1].get()
        return value



root = tk.Tk()
label_RADEC = ['RA','DEC']
label_Time = ['LST','local time']
# Create first frame
frame1 = MyFrame(root, num_labels=2, num_entries=2, num_buttons=2, label_names=label_RADEC)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# Access the first entry
first_entry_value = frame1.get_first_entry()

print(first_entry_value)

root.mainloop()
```

Updated with method to gel all entries as array.
Now it prints empty array at start, but if I input other values in the entries, still doesn't print anything

```
'',''
```

Comment: Can you add a `get` method to your class that returns an array of the text in all the entries?

Comment: Sure, I've update the question. A small improvement. It prints an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that `get_entries` isn't working, it's that you're using it in the wrong way.

When you first call `get_entries` and print the results, it's before the user has had a chance to enter anything so it prints a list of empty strings.

When you call `get_entries` by pressing the button, it computes the values just fine. However, because it only returns the values, the values are thrown away since the caller (`mainloop`) ignores the return values of all functions it calls since it doesn't know what to do with them.

You can see this by adding a `print` statement inside `get_entries`. When you  do that, you can see it's getting the values just fine:

```
def get_entries(self):
    result = [entry.get() for entry in self.entries]
    print(f"get_entries result: {result}")
    return result
```

When I insert "this is RA" in the first entry, and "this is DEC" in the second entry, when I press the button I get this output:

```
get_entries result: ['this is RA', 'this is DEC']
```

If you leave the `return` statement in, you can use it to get the values outside of the class. It's just that you must do so after the user has entered values and not before.

Comment: I've re-edited the code in the question. It still doesn't get the value out.If I put print(value), it prints on the console, but I need the value out so I can further work with it.

Comment: @Adrian: like the answer says, you can work on it, but you have to realize that you're working in an event-driven framework. You have to give the user a chance to enter the data before your code can work on it. So, for example, you can add another button that calls a function that gets the result of `get_entries` and then uses the result to do the further work.

Comment: @Adrian: even though you've removed `get_entries` in the update, the problem is the same for `get_first_entry` and `get_second_entry`: you have to wait for the user to enter data before you can call the functions and use the results.